# Interfaces without Modports

Tags: system-verilog

SystemVerilog interfaces have really simplified my FPGA designs. They allow me to route many signals to multiple blocks in logical groupings. I really like them. I use them with modports to indicate the in/out directions. In the two books I've read on SystemVerilog, interfaces are introduced and the syntax is shown before modports.  At the end of the chapter/section, modports are introduced as a helpful way to use interfaces. As far as I can tell, I would never use an interface if the concept of a modport did not exist. So, this brings me to my question...

Are there usage cases for interfaces that make sense without using modports?

The usage case could be in implementation/synthesis or in verification/simulation. I'm mostly curious to learn something new here about interfaces. I looked for related questions but didn't see any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**modport**s are intended for tools (like synthesis) that compile a design with boundaries that require direction information. If you flatten out the hierarchy with an embedded interface, there's no need for directions. Simulation tools almost always do this, so **interface**s used just for verification do not need modports.

Some people put `modport`s in `interface`s for verification as a way of restricting access to certain signals, but unfortunately, many simulation tools do not enforce the direction, especially when used with a `virtual interface`.